# Can I have an if statement inside a map object to handle null values?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

So i'm doing some web scraping of a bunch of products on a page & my code works fine as long as the elements are there, though sometimes when a product is out of stock and an element isn't present on a page I get the following error.

I've tried to put some kind of "If statement" inside the map object though can't get it to work.

```
//This code works if all the elements are present on the page
const productsOnPage = await page.$$eval('.tile-product', as => as.map(productContainer => ({
      productTitle: productContainer.querySelector('h3').innerText.trim(),

    }))
    );

//I want something like this to handle the null values


    const productsOnPage = await page.$$eval('.tile-product', as => as.map(productContainer => ({
      if ( productContainer.querySelector('h3').innerText.length  <= 0 || null ) {
      productTitle: productContainer.querySelector('h3').innerText.trim(),
    }
      else {
        productTitle: '',
      }

    }))
    );
```

If null I expect:

```
productTitle: "";
```

but i'm getting:

```
Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator, E.g

```
const productsOnPage = await page.$$eval('.tile-product', as => as.map(productContainer => ({
      productTitle: productContainer.querySelector('h3') ? productContainer.querySelector('h3').innerText.trim() : '';
    }))
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

People already answered with the correct solution. But I believe an explanation is needed. On your if statement `productContainer.querySelector('h3').innerText.length` you're checking the length of the `innerText` property from `querySelector('h3')`. 
But you must verify if the
querySelector('h3') exists before reading its properties.